# How to extract data from line in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have a file with 10m lines, with each line like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("567f972cad55ac0797baa773"), "id" : 357103 }
```

For each line, I need to do something with its `"id"` value.

So far I have:

```
listings.each.with_index do |line, idx|
  # listing_id = JSON.parse(line).fetch("id") #>> invalid JSON error
  # line.split('"id : "') #=> some gibberish
  line.match(/"id" : (.*)/)[1] #=> "357103 }"
```

`parse` throws an error that the lines are not valid json. `split` returns some gibberish. The closest result I got to my expectation was `match`, but it returns for the above example `"357103 }"`.

Can you please help me fix it?

Comment: Is the format (supposed to be) JSON? If it is, then mention it. Not just use JSON method suddenly in the code and expect the reader to guess why. If it is not JSON, then don't use JSON method.

Comment: It usually is JSON format, but i have done wrong extraction last night and i have no idea about ruby. and it was either ask you guys for help or wait another 20h to extract correctly formatted file.

Comment: That looks like MongoDB data. Try to export it as JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Splitting is faster than Regex here. With such a large file, it might make a noticeable difference.

Also, it looks like you need to escape those double quotes: `line.split("\"id\" : ")`

```
> puts Benchmark.measure{line.split("\"id\" : ").last.delete('}').delete(' ')}
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000020)

> puts Benchmark.measure{line.match(/\s(\d+)\s/)[1]}
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000043)
```

**Update**

Even faster, use splitting all the way:

```
> puts Benchmark.measure{line.split("\"id\" : ").last.split(' ').first }
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000008)
```

**Edit**

Though as Stefan mentions in his comment, it looks like your file is BSON (MongoDB) not JSON. There is a Mongo [gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/mongo/versions/2.2.5).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `\s(\d+)\s` regex, no JSON parsing is required.

```
line.match(/\s(\d+)\s/)[1] #=> "357103"
```

Answer (score 1):

Are the ids made up of all numbers? You can try using a regex that looks for a colon then a list of numbers.

```
Line.match(/"id " : [0-9]+/)
```

Looks for Id followed by any length of integers.

If it has letters and numbers then:

```
Line.match(/"id" :[[:alnum:]]+/)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just match using splicing:

```
line[/(?<= )\d+/] = 357103
```